# Filling a row with values above

Tags: excel, vba

this macro is for filling empty rows with values from the row above. I would need to adjust it, so that all the columns are being filled and not only B column. Thanks!

```
Sub FillColBlanks()
'by Dave Peterson  2004-01-06
'fill blank cells in column with value above
'http://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim col As Long

Set wks = ActiveSheet
With wks
col = activecell.column
'or
'col = .range("b1").column

Set rng = .UsedRange  'try to reset the lastcell
LastRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(LastRow, col)) _
              .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "No blanks found"
   Exit Sub
Else
   rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End If

'replace formulas with values
 With .Cells(1, col).EntireColumn
   .Value = .Value
End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Then loop through columns? What have you tried so far? This is relatively easy considering it looks like you have done most of the 'heavy lifting'.

Comment: Hello Bruce, I only googled for the most suitable code. I tried:
change col = activecell.column' - deleted
or - deleted
col = .range("A:J").column - adjusted

But with no success. I am not a very advanced user, so I probably cannot do anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through column A to J (`For i = 1 to 10` in the code).  You can adjust as necessary.

```
Sub FillColBlanks()
'by Dave Peterson  2004-01-06
'fill blank cells in column with value above
'http://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html
Dim wks     As Worksheet
Dim rng     As Range
Dim emptyRng As Range
Dim i       As Long

Set wks = ActiveSheet

With wks
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row, i))
        On Error Resume Next
        Set emptyRng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If emptyRng Is Nothing Then    ' If we have empty cells, do the following
            MsgBox ("No blanks found")
            'Exit Sub ' Commented this out because you want to keep looping through columns, not exit sub.
        Else
            emptyRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
            rng.EntireColumn.Value = rng.EntireColumn.Value
        End If
    Next i
End With                     'wks

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Bruce, this macro runs quite slow, is there a possibility to adjust it? Moreover, sometimes I get only zeros in my columns.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Also, try changing `rng.EntireColumn...` to just `rng.Value = rng.Value` as it won't have to run over the entire column.  Also, add `Application.Screenupdating = False` at the top, then turn it to `True` at the end.

Comment: I only changed the part with rng.Value and now it works immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub FillColBlanks()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I always get: "runtime error 438.
Object does not support this property or method."
Should I adjust something?

Comment: Yes I tried, but unfortunately it did not work at all. I was given only zeros everywhere and crosses in the rest of the spreadsheet. :)